# Magento 1.8 <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?> code shows " /> and also can't login

Tags: magento-1.8, login

Am using Magento 1.8 in my store all view.phtm page after form showing one code like

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<esi:include src=" https:="" www.abc.in="" varnishcache="" getformkey="" "="">" />
```

I think this code will shows

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Comment: Is it working when you remove `<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>` code?

Comment: No it's not working Thanks for replay @JaiminSutariya